# iOS test flight still just for iOS 8

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Is the iOS TestFlight still just for iOS 8? I am trying to give beta users access to my app through the iTunesConnect and I wanted to know if earlier versions of iOS can access it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is iOS8+ only, as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/):

> TestFlight can be used to test iOS apps on iPhone, iPad, and iPod
>   touch running iOS 8 or later. Mac apps cannot be tested.

Answer (score 0):

test flight itself works on iOS starting at 2 or 3 ;)

**but the new APPLE testflight via iTunesConnect - yes is ios8+ only**